# How can I build a dual potentiometer?

Tags: oscillator, potentiometer, circuit-design, wien-bridge

I am about to build a wien bridge oscillator circuit which is shown in the figure below:

[image]

However, I need a dual potentiometer to do so, because the resistors VR1a and VR1b must have the same value always, and this is hard to achieve using two single potentiometers.

The problem is that I think that dual potentiometers are not available in the local market. Can I build a dual pot from two single pots? Is there another way to have a dual pot?

Comment: "that I think [...] are not available" don't think, go and check. Unless you live in a part of the planet (or outside) where there is no stereo audio equipment within many many miles, I somewhat doubt that they are not available.

Comment: Do you have mail service where you are? You can easily order these for a dollar or two for a cheap carbon pot. Cermet will cost more. Otherwise this is a mechanical engineering question and off-topic, I think.

Comment: I checked two local electronics stores and they don't have this equipment. I will continue searching...

Comment: @ammarx: try asking the people that work there. Or salvage one from an old stereo. Or even order something online, use ebay if you must, those things are everywhere.

Comment: As Plasma says- I believe it's the balance control that's typically linear ('B' taper) 100K ganged pots. They've simplified this to put two elements on a single substrate in some cases, but I would avoid that construction if possible (I doubt they'll match as well);.

Comment: You can buy dual ganged pots at digikey or other supply houses.  If you search for dual ganged potentiometer there is a youtube video of someone making one.

Comment: I agree, if your trying to match the value of the pots with any degree of accuracy a dual pot is not going to meed your needs.

Comment: Then how to build a variable frequency wien bridge?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look in Mouser finds some dual pots made by Alpha.  They are not as common as they once were I think, some don't expect to find them in a store. 
Or get them from Amazon.  Amazon has EVERYTHING.